# How to lookup encrypted data with sql keyword 'like'

Tags: sql, search, encryption, mariadb

I know it is a really strange question.There are some columns in my database using RSA for data encrytion.But front-end is using instance searching. So, I need matching the encrypted data with part of the plaintext.

eg:the original text is **"stackoverflow"**,and it is encrypted in database. When the front-end input get plaintext "**stack**" ,the encryted **"stackoverflow"** should be matched.

I know there is a solution: Load all data, decrypt and match.And Huge usage of memory.So, How to deal this within database? what should I do if I want to use the keyword 'like'?

Comment: Seems like a product specific issue. Tag the dbms used.

Comment: I would say that it can be a generic question, I have a patent application for something similar :) https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?II=3&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20160224&CC=EP&NR=2988291A1&KC=A1

Comment: Well, I'd say it depends on the implementation. Some dbms products have built-in encryption, others haven't. More info is needed to give a good advice.

Comment: It depends on which *properties* of encryption you're happy to give up, in a trade-off against being able to perform wildcard searches. At some point, you've traded away so much security (by e.g. forcing all equal plaintext values to be identically encrypted, or possibly having to encrypt smaller runs, again identically for equal inputs) that you may as well not have the encryption at all.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Database:mariadb. Encrypt Algorithm: 1024 RSA, not  a built-in encrytion.

Comment: If the encryption is being done in the _client_, then you have to decrypt in the _client_?  In that case, `LIKE` needs to be simulated in the _client_, and you need to read the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a limited number of keywords that can be searched for, and if showing them in plaintext does not compromise security, then I suggest the following...

As you insert the text (encrypted by the client) into the table, also insert the relevant plaintext words into another column.  Then use `FULLTEXT` on that column.

`FULLTEXT` would be much faster, but has limitations.